# Image Slider with fixed content

Tags: jquery, slider

i want to build a slider similar to https://www.airbnb.com.sg/

where the content remains constant , just the background image gets slided.

can you suggest me any jquery plugin with similar requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were in your place, I would use [flex slider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) to slide images in background and place my static content over slider using css absolute positioning.

first create a big slider using flex slider.

create your static content, for example:

```
<div id="staticContent"> 
   <!-- your content such as form or anything goes here-->
</div>
```

make this static content div absolute positioned.

```
#staticContent{
  position:absolute;
  left:20%;
  top:20%; /*change these values*/
}
```

Comment: I worked perfectly with  NivoSlider , just i added zindex to CSS class. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try [NivoSlider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/).It's a good one.